# AWS EC2 instance based on RHEL7.2 ami can not install Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, rhel7

I created one EC2 instance that's based on ***AMI***: **RHEL-7.2_HVM-20161025-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2 - ami-2265c543** , but when I wanna install docker via `yum install docker -y` it shows me error: `No package docker available. Error: Nothing to do` . So anyone know how to install docker on this ami OS?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install *Docker-CE* by setting up Docker repo.

To do So, you can follow [official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository) (**Use Docker EE for RHEL**).

**Install required packages**

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils \
device-mapper-persistent-data \
lvm2
```

**Use the following command to set up the stable repository**

```
sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

**INSTALL DOCKER CE**

```
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

**Start Docker**

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: You will still need to run sudo usermod -a -G docker USER and reboot the instance to run docker commands without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

AWS — RHLE7.5 Free Tier with Docker CE
Since docker is considered an “Extra” rpm with RHLE, then let's explain how you can use Centos Docker Community Edition (CE) for RHLE.

The above step of installing helped me to resolve the problem.
Below I am listing steps to install docker-ce on RHEL.

sudo yum install -y yum-utils

sudo yum-config-manager — add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

sudo yum makecache fast

To avoid error “Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9” 
Run following command

sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.42-1.gitad8f0f7.el7.noarch.rpm

To avoid error “libtool-ltdl-2.4.2–22.el7_3.x8 FAILED” Run following command

yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-22.el7_3.x86_64.rpm

To avoid Error: Package: docker-ce-18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)

Run:
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/pigz-2.3.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum -y install docker-ce

Can test the docker running with command: sudo systemctl start docker

To check to see if your service is running you can use:

sudo service docker status